# Issue with SQL getting Upcoming Birthdays

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone fix the following SQL code, which gets upcoming birthdays:

```
SELECT *
FROM personal
WHERE 1 = ( FLOOR( DATEDIFF( DATE_ADD( DATE( NOW( ) ) , INTERVAL :interval DAY ) , dob ) / 365.25 ) ) -
      ( FLOOR( DATEDIFF( DATE_ADD( DATE( NOW( ) ) , INTERVAL -1 DAY ) , dob ) / 365.25 ) )
ORDER BY MONTH( dob ), DAY( dob )
LIMIT :rangeStart,:limit
```

It works aside from there is a bug with the ordering if the year rolls over. E.g. your in December checking ahead 1 month, then January birthday will get ordered before December.
I've seen a few posts on here about doing this, but none of them seem to get this part correct. I tried using the following ORDER BY clause, from another post and which seemed to work for someone else, but when I run it I get a syntax error:

```
ORDER BY ( MONTH(dob) > MONTH(NOW() OR ((MONTH(dob) = MONTH(NOW()) AND DAY(dob) >= DAY(NOW()) DESC, MONTH(dob), DAY(dob)
```

Comment: In your first query, you only order by Month and Day. Have you tried something like `ORDER BY YEAR( dob ) ASC, MONTH( dob ) ASC, DAY( dob ) ASC`

Comment: Agree with @kschieck, but I think the `YEAR(dob)` should be ordered ASC.

Comment: Yeah, I realized after. Thanks.

Comment: Year of dob is the date of birth year, so it can't be used in an order - otherwise Jan 2nd 2002 would come before Jan 1st 2011.

Comment: It seems like ordering by YEAR(dob) will not solve the problem. As I understand the problem the year the person was born is irrelevant. The  order should be based on the year of his next birthday.

Comment: Are you at all concerned with performance? At present, all solutions will perform a full table scan of all rows to formulate the result set. Are you able to modify the table or add indexes?

Comment: I'm not worried about performance at this time. Soon I will move over to use a calendar, so the birthdays will be stored as calendar events and this function (well probably an adaptation of it) will only be needed when the record is created/modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated answer ...**

Thought of a cleaner way to accomplish this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
  SELECT *
      ,DATE_ADD( MAKEDATE( YEAR( NOW() ), DAYOFYEAR( dob ) )
                ,INTERVAL IF( DAYOFYEAR( dob ) < DAYOFYEAR( NOW() ), 1, 0 ) YEAR
               )
       AS next_birthday

  FROM personal
 ) a

 WHERE a.next_birthday < DATE_ADD( NOW(), INTERVAL :interval DAY )

 ORDER BY a.next_birthday ASC

 LIMIT :rangeStart,:limit
```

Explanation: next_birthday is calculated by taking this year's birthday and adding either 1 or 0 years to it depending on whether or not the birthday has already occurred this year - determined by `IF( DAYOFYEAR( dob ) < DAYOFYEAR( NOW() ), 1, 0 )`.

See it in action in SQLFiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6471/1. Play with the number of days to see January after December.

**Original answer ...**

Add the following to your SELECT:

```
SELECT *
, CASE WHEN MAKEDATE( YEAR( CURRENT_DATE ), DAYOFYEAR( dob ) ) >= CURRENT_DATE
       THEN MAKEDATE( YEAR( CURRENT_DATE ), DAYOFYEAR( dob ) )
       ELSE DATE_ADD( MAKEDATE( YEAR( CURRENT_DATE ), DAYOFYEAR( dob ) ), INTERVAL 1 YEAR )
  END AS next_birthday
```

then

```
ORDER BY next_birthday ASC
```

Rewriting your original query you get something like:

```
SELECT a.*

  FROM ( SELECT *
              , CASE WHEN DAYOFYEAR( dob ) >= DAYOFYEAR( CURRENT_DATE )
                     THEN MAKEDATE( YEAR( CURRENT_DATE ), DAYOFYEAR( dob ) )
                     ELSE DATE_ADD( MAKEDATE( YEAR( CURRENT_DATE ), DAYOFYEAR( dob ) ), INTERVAL 1 YEAR )
                END AS next_birthday
           FROM personal
       ) a

 WHERE a.next_birthday < DATE_ADD( CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL :interval DAY )

 ORDER BY a.next_birthday ASC

 LIMIT :rangeStart,:limit
```

Comment: I think you have a mistake.. you only use CURRENT_DATE and never 'dob', so all results of next_birthday are the same.

Comment: I still get `next_birthday` set as today for all results when I run this.

Comment: oops - missed one of the DAYOFYEARs. Try it now. Can you provide some sample data so I can test?

Comment: Your updated answer gives me the same results as the answer I found - so it works. As your answer doesn't rely on dividing by 365.25 it seems like it must be more accurate though, so I am going to use this code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've now found a solution. For those that would like to know, the final code is:

```
SELECT *, DATE_ADD( dob, INTERVAL YEAR( FROM_DAYS( DATEDIFF( NOW( ), dob) -1 ) ) + 1 YEAR) AS next_birthday
FROM personal
WHERE 1 = ( FLOOR( DATEDIFF( DATE_ADD( DATE( NOW( ) ) , INTERVAL :interval DAY ) , dob ) / 365.25 ) ) -
          ( FLOOR( DATEDIFF( DATE_ADD( DATE( NOW( ) ) , INTERVAL -1 DAY ) , dob ) / 365.25 ) )
ORDER BY next_birthday ASC
LIMIT :rangeStart,:limit
```

I haven't tested it fully, but on simple tests it works.

Comment: The problem with using actual dates of birth to calculate birthday dates is regarding to indexing: the functions will make it not possible for the optimizer to use indexes.

Comment: This issue would be easier solved if all birthdays were stored at a given year (ie. 2000). A query to get the birthdays within a date range would just require a simple `select ... where birthday2000 between '2000-m1-d1' and '2000-m2-d2'` and this new column could be held by a trigger or a calculated column (if dbms support indexing calculated columns).